# Web API throwing unhandled exception error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following DB call made through Web API:

```
public IEnumerable<PogStoreData> GetStoreSetData(string FloorplanIdList, string PogIdList, string PogName, string Season, string Version,
            string PogStatusList, Nullable<DateTime> IssueDate, Nullable<DateTime> StartDate, Nullable<DateTime> LiveDate, 
            Nullable<DateTime> ExpirationDate, string PogMoveTypeList)
{
    // Create the parameters collection
    var parameters = new Collection<SqlParameter>();

    // Add each parameter.  Entity will not work without all params in the correct order
    parameters.Add(StoredProcedureParameterBuilder.StringParam("@fpIdList", string.IsNullOrEmpty(FloorplanIdList) ? null : FloorplanIdList, -1));
    parameters.Add(StoredProcedureParameterBuilder.StringParam("@pogIdList", string.IsNullOrEmpty(PogIdList) ? null : PogIdList, -1));
    parameters.Add(StoredProcedureParameterBuilder.StringParam("@pogName", string.IsNullOrEmpty(PogName) ? null : PogName, 100));
    parameters.Add(StoredProcedureParameterBuilder.StringParam("@season", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Season) ? null : Season, -1));
    parameters.Add(StoredProcedureParameterBuilder.StringParam("@version", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Version) ? null : Version, -1));
    parameters.Add(StoredProcedureParameterBuilder.StringParam("@pogStatusList", string.IsNullOrEmpty(PogStatusList) ? null : PogStatusList, 10));
    parameters.Add(StoredProcedureParameterBuilder.StringParam("@issueDate", IssueDate.HasValue ? IssueDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : null, 20));
    parameters.Add(StoredProcedureParameterBuilder.StringParam("@startDate", StartDate.HasValue ? StartDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : null, 20));
    parameters.Add(StoredProcedureParameterBuilder.StringParam("@liveDate", LiveDate.HasValue ? LiveDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : null, 20));
    parameters.Add(StoredProcedureParameterBuilder.StringParam("@expirationDate", ExpirationDate.HasValue ? ExpirationDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : null, 20));
    parameters.Add(StoredProcedureParameterBuilder.StringParam("@pogMoveList", string.IsNullOrEmpty(PogMoveTypeList) ? null : PogMoveTypeList, 10));

    return SelectList<PogStoreData>("spc.SPA_get_store_set_data_by_criteria", parameters);
}
```

Following is the code for SelectList:

```
private IEnumerable<T> SelectList<T>(string inStoredProcedure, ICollection<SqlParameter> inParameters)
{
    string paramNames = string.Join(",", inParameters.Select(parameter => parameter.ParameterName).ToList());
    string sqlString = inStoredProcedure + " " + paramNames;
    object[] paramValues = inParameters.Cast<object>().ToArray();

    if (paramValues.Length > 0)
        return this.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sqlString, paramValues).ToList();
    else
        return this.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sqlString).ToList();
}
```

But when I pass value only for PogStatus list I am getting the following error:
The cast to value type 'System.Double' failed because the materialized value is null.
I am getting the above error in SqlQuery(sqlString).ToList() statement.
I don't know how to resolve this one. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason is you have a field/property of type `double` in your `PogStoreData` type, but the query returns null for it.

Try to execute this stored procedure directly in database (e.g. in Management Studio) and compare the result with data you expect to receive.